# How to summarize the top 3 highest values in a dataset when there are ties

Tags: r, dplyr, top-n

I have a data frame (my_data) and want to calculate the sum of only the 3 highest values even though there might be ties. I am quite new to R and I've used `dplyr`.

```
A tibble: 15 x 3
   city      month number
   <chr>     <chr>  <dbl>
 1 Lund      jan       12
 2 Lund      feb       12
 3 Lund      mar       18
 4 Lund      apr       28
 5 Lund      may       28
 6 Stockholm jan       15
 7 Stockholm feb       15
 8 Stockholm mar       30
 9 Stockholm apr       30
10 Stockholm may       10
11 Uppsala   jan       22
12 Uppsala   feb       30
13 Uppsala   mar       40
14 Uppsala   apr       60
15 Uppsala   may       30
```

This is the code  I have tried:

```
# For each city, count the top 3 of variable number
my_data %>% group_by(city) %>% top_n(3, number) %>% summarise(top_nr = sum(number))
```

The expected (wanted) output is:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  city      top_nr
  <chr>      <dbl>
1 Lund          86
2 Stockholm     75
3 Uppsala      130
```

but the actual R output is:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  city      top_nr
  <chr>      <dbl>
1 Lund          86
2 Stockholm     90
3 Uppsala      160
```

It seems like if there are ties, all tied values are included in the  summation. I wanted only 3 unique instances with highest values to be counted.

Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: Your example and output numbers showed seems to be different.  Is it on a different dataset

Comment: Please use `dput` to provide your data so it is easier to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @NelsonGon I didn't know about the dput function. I will use it in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Life might be way simpler without `top_n()`:

```
dat %>%
  group_by(city) %>%
  summarize(
    top_nr = sum(tail(sort(number), 3))
    )
```

Comment: Wow! Very succinct! But as an R-amateur I find the part : sum(tail(sort(number), 3)), quite hard to understand (even thoug it sloved the problem necely).

Comment: Starting from the middle it `sort`s the `number` in *ascending order*; after that `tail` returns *last 3* numbers from the previous result, and pass those numbers into the `sum` function,  which adds them together.

Comment: Nice! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 6):

We can do a `distinct` to remove the duplicate elements.  The way in which `top_n` works is that if the values are duplicated, it will keep that many dupe rows

```
my_data %>% 
   distinct(city, number, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
   group_by(city) %>%
   top_n(3, number) %>%
   summarise(top_nr = sum(number))
```

#### Update

Based on the OP's new output, after the `top_n` output (which is not `arrange`d), get the 'number' arranged in descending order and get the `sum` of first 3 'number'

```
my_data %>% 
   group_by(city) %>% 
   top_n(3, number) %>% 
   arrange(city,  desc(number)) %>% 
   summarise(number = sum(head(number, 3)))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  city      number
#  <chr>      <int>
#1 Lund          74
#2 Stockholm     75
#3 Uppsala      130
```

#### data

```
my_data <- structure(list(city = c("Lund", "Lund", "Lund", "Lund", "Lund", 
"Stockholm", "Stockholm", "Stockholm", "Stockholm", "Stockholm", 
"Uppsala", "Uppsala", "Uppsala", "Uppsala", "Uppsala"), month = c("jan", 
"feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", 
"jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may"), number = c(12L, 12L, 18L, 
28L, 28L, 15L, 15L, 30L, 30L, 10L, 22L, 30L, 40L, 60L, 30L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15"))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun but when I run your suggested code I get

Comment: Why use `head` here? I tried something similar and got weird results.

Comment: @NelsonGon  Based on the new output, the OP is not discarding the dupes, but taking the first 3 only, top_n gives as many rows as  there are dupes

Comment: Ooh, I see. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @akrun nice solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This `tidyverse` (actually, `dplyr`) solution is almost equal to [akrun's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56092539/how-to-summarize-the-top-3-highest-values-in-a-dataset-when-there-are-ties/56092566#56092566), but `filter`s the dataframe instead of getting the `top_n`.

```
library(tidyverse)

my_data %>%
  group_by(city) %>%
  arrange(desc(number), .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  filter(row_number() %in% 1:3) %>%
  summarise(top_nr = sum(number))
## A tibble: 3 x 2
#  city      top_nr
#  <chr>      <int>
#1 Lund          74
#2 Stockholm     75
#3 Uppsala      130
```